# css is wrongly displayed when using php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to access to a laravel 4.2 project from an external machine, to do that I need to use `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0`.
this is working well and all css files are running when I open a browser from the virtual machine that contains the project.

result :

[image]

But when try to enter the web application from external machine (inside the same network), css seems to load but not correctly.

result :

[image]

all css/js files are reachable and no 404 errors from the external machine

Please help;
Cheers

Comment: View the source in the browser, are the paths to the CSS files correct? Can you click on them and they open? Are there any messages in your browser's developer console?

Comment: Beside the source tab in your browser. Could you may provide the code, which embed the css and js files?

Comment: Yes, all css/js files are perfectly accessible and no 404 error on them